# How to reshape data for Decision Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm working on a Machine Learning class and have followed instructions for a simple example of decision trees. the Code works, until I get to predicting results. I get the following error:

"ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[10.  1.  4.  0.  0.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Code:
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
    clf = clf.fit(X, y)

```
print(clf.predict([10, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0]))
print(clf.predict([10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]))
```

I'm not entirely sure how to "reshape" the predict call. I tried googling it, but the asnwers don't make sense to me.

Comment: I see you delete your question, for prevent downvotes you can check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass [[10,1,4,0,0,0]]  in your predict function rather [10,1,4,0,0,0], by passing 1D array it means that your are passing 6 example with single feature, now by making it 2D it now means you are passing one example with 6 features on which you have trained the model